Prevent OnValidSubmit when task already running
Ive got a Blazor/.NET8 webapp and I am struggling with a user registration Component. The issue is that I cant seem to create a way to conditionally either prevent the task from running nor disable the button from subsequent clicks.
I have tried adding a private bool and conditionally running the task based on its value but it appears as though the submit was somehow resetting the bool back to false. At this point I have extended this theory and created a "StateService" thinking that this would persist the value, but its acting the same:
namespace TripSuite.Service
{
    public interface IStateService
    {
        bool IsSubmitting { get; set; }
    }
    public class StateService : IStateService
    {
        public bool IsSubmitting { get; set; } = false;
    }
}


In the program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStateService, StateService>();

the component:
<EditForm Model="Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit" FormName="register">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <hr />
            <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger" />
            </div>


    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Disabled="@stateService.IsSubmitting">Register</MudButton>
  
   


        </EditForm>

the CS:
    private async void HandleSubmit()
    {
        if (!stateService.IsSubmitting)
        {

            stateService.IsSubmitting = true;

            StateHasChanged();

            await RegisterUser();
        }
      
    }

what I dont quite understand is that if i comment out the "await RegisterUser();" then the UI acts as expected where the submit buttons becomes disabled.
I dont think its all that relevent but this is the RegisterUser method which creates the user and sets up some defaults.
public async Task RegisterUser()
{
             
        var user = CreateUser();
        await UserStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var emailStore = GetEmailStore();
        await emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);



        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            identityErrors = result.Errors;

            return;

        }




        var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var callbackUrl = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(
            NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Account/ConfirmEmail").AbsoluteUri,
            new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["userId"] = userId, ["code"] = code, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });

    await EmailSender.SendConfirmationLinkAsync(user, Input.Email, HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));


   
    var usersCount = await UserManager.Users.CountAsync();
    if (usersCount == 1) // The first user has just been created.
    {

        
        var adminRoleExists = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
        if (!adminRoleExists)
        {
            await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        }

        
        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");

       
        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("Permission", "CanAccessEverything"));

    }

       
        var newUserSettings = new UserSettings
            {

                UserID = userId,
                SelectedTheme = "Dark"
            };

        var newEntity = new Entities
            {
                Email = user.Email,
                UserID = userId,
                EntityType = Enums.EntityTypes.WebUser
            };

        DB.Entities.Add(newEntity);
        DB.UserSettings.Add(newUserSettings);
        await DB.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (UserManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
        {
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
                "Account/RegisterConfirmation",
                new() { ["email"] = Input.Email, ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl });
        }
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
             
        RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
}

Im at a loss here, seems like this should be a simple thing.
edit-
Ive created a fresh server-side application and with using the initial identity scaffolded register component have tried a simple test which still allows for OnValidSubmit to be spammed
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <StatusMessage Message="@Message" />
    <EditForm Model="Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="RegisterUser" FormName="register">
       


        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled="@_isSubmitting">Register</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

private bool _isSubmitting = false;

public async Task RegisterUser(EditContext editContext)
{
    if (!_isSubmitting)
    {
        _isSubmitting = true;
        await Task.Delay(100);
        //register routine here
        _isSubmitting = false;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}


It looks like you're using a Singleton service for SPA session scoped data?

I am relatively new to Blazor, It was my understanding that the service would intialize once and be used as a single instance throughout the scope and lifteime of the application

This line:
private async void HandleSubmit()

should be
private async Task HandleSubmit()

See for more information on why - Blazor UI Update Async void vs Async Task
Updated Answer
I don't have MudBlazor installed so can't reproduce all your code.  However, here's a very simple form that demonstrates the principle of what I believe you are trying to achieve.  You should be able to adapt it to your situation:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<div>
    <EditForm Model="data" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit">
        <button type="submit" disabled="@_isProcessing" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code{
    private bool _isProcessing;
    private string data = string.Empty;

    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        _isProcessing = true;
        await this.RegisterUser();
        _isProcessing = false;
    }

    private async Task RegisterUser()
    {
        // Fake your calls to register the user
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}


Ive tried with task prior to void method which resulted in the same behavior

See revised answer.  What Render Mode and Render Location are you using?

Im using server side rendering, I assume that it would use InteractiveServer but I dont have the set explicitly. The application has massive focus on data and not alot of need for wasm.

Need to always check in questions nowadays!  As long as it's set in App.razor that's OK.

Things change fast out there! the App.razor sets "<Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />"

So what's private static IComponentRenderMode renderModeForPage = InteractiveServer; set to?

it looks like this, from what i gather its not set unless the path start with "/Account" :     [CascadingParameter]
private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
    ? null
    : InteractiveServer;


I dont want to hard conclude it, but this appears to have started operating as expected after deleting the bin and obj folders and doing a rebuild. Which this is exactly where I started a couple days ago. I cant explain this but Ill take it!
